# Does Apple allow for 3rd party apps on one phone to access the general settings on a different iphone? (if both phones confirmed passcode)

Tags: iphone

From an end user perspective: Could I enter a passcode in the general settings for one iPhone, and then access the general settings for that iphone using my own iphone (along with entering a passcode)?

Comment: What sort of "general settings" are you looking to access?

Comment: The enable restrictions settings!

Comment: It might help to state the exact problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Apps cannot access general settings on a stock iOS device, either locally or remotely.  They are all run inside a security sandbox with limited permissions.